# Can't seem to trim all leading whitespace - JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, trim

I'm trying to trim all leading whitespace from a textarea input box with this code:

```
replaceString = replaceString.replace(/^\s+|^\t+|\t+|\s+$/g, "");
```

When I do that, I go from

```
    .map_image #map_link_0 { width: 40px; height: 42px; top: 11px; left: 11px; }
    .map_image #map_link_1 { width: 47px; height: 42px; top: 62px; left: 19px; }
```

to

```
.map_image #map_link_0 { width: 40px; height: 42px; top: 11px; left: 11px; }
 .map_image #map_link_1 { width: 47px; height: 42px; top: 62px; left: 19px; }
```

What am I doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MikeKelley/tu2be69x/)

Comment: `^` character only make sense in the begining of regex and inside character class (`[...]`)

Comment: Well from the example you pasted it looks like the code did just what you wanted - removed two leading spaces. Do you want to do that in every line of input maybe?

Comment: @Paweł Chorążyk, that's my goal, yes. I'm not very good with regex.

Comment: I'm tired this morning. I didn't even realize I tagged the question JavaScript/jQuery when I was actually asking about a regex. Sorry folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression by default doesn't consider multiple lines, so `^` is only matching the very beginning of your input. You can fix this by adding the multiline `/m` flag (for a total of `/gm`).

From [Mozilla's JS RE docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> `^` Matches beginning of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately after a line break character.
>
> `$` Matches end of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately before a line break character.

Comment: That did it. I wasn't aware of a multiline flag. I seem to have misunderstood the purpose of the global flag.

Comment: I expected the same thing you did, but it varies by language (eg. `gsub` would have worked in Ruby). In JS, `/g` is only "global" to the line.